# How to get full text when scraping with beautifulsoup in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape website - product description... but the problem is that I am not getting full description of product, but just part of it (this is the output):

```
                                               about
0  [\n, [Descrizione], \n, [], [Allenamento per p...
```

And here's my code:

```
def perform_search(kodovi):
    i = 0
    c = 0
    for x in kodovi:
        k = requests.get(searchlink).text
        soup=BeautifulSoup(k,'html.parser')
    
        productlist = soup.find_all("ul",{"class":"products-grid"})

        for product in productlist:
            link = product.find("a",{"class":"product-image"}).get('href')
            productlinks.append(link)
            print("Done")


def scraping_data(productlinks,r):
    for link in productlinks:
        f = requests.get(link,headers=headers).text
        hun=BeautifulSoup(f,'html.parser')

#Here I get description of product
        try:
            about=hun.find("div",{"class":"std"})
        except:
            about=None
            print("nothing found")

        try:
            name=hun.find("h1",{"class":"product-main__name"}).text.replace('\n',"")
        except:
            name=None

        whisky = {"about":about}

        data.append(whisky)
        r=r+1
        print("completed",r)

    df = pd.DataFrame(data)

    print(df)
```

So actually the final question is how can I get full product description if it's structured like this:

```
<div class="std">
<h2>Descrizione</h2>
<p></p><p>A LOT OF TEXT WITH PRODUCT DESCRIPTION......</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[I can't reproduce it exactly without knowing the link/s you're scraping from, but] I suspect that your code *is* getting the full description, but `print(df)` truncates it to maintain that tabular display.

You could examine it all as a spreadsheet with [`df.to_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) or even [`df.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) or you could add a line to print all of just the cell in first row's "about" column

```py
print(df['about'].iloc[0])
```

```py
print(list(df['about']))
```

will print the "about" column as a list and

```py
print(list(df.iloc[0]))
```

will print the first row as a list.